# c++ memory issue about pointer + non pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Let's say I have declared a variable

```
vector<int>* interList = new vector<int>();
interList->push_back(1);
interList->push_back(2);
interList->push_back(3);
interList->push_back(4);
```

First question is when I push_back an int, a memory space will be consumed?

Second question if I (delete interList), will the memory consume by 1,2,3,4 be released automatically?

EDIT: free --> delete

Comment: When you say "free", do you mean `free`? Or `delete`?

Comment: why `vector<int>* interList`, why not just: `vector<int> interList`?

Comment: Q: when I push_back an int, a memory space will be consumed?  A: Yes.  Q: if I free(interList) ... will the memory be released?  A: You won't call "free".  But if you erase() elements, or "delete" the vector - yes, the memory will be freed.

Comment: @billz, i need this vector to be passed around

Comment: @henry Then use ``void foo(vector<int> &)`` instead of ``void f(vector<int> *)``, be c++-style.

Comment: @gongzhitaao, what's wrong with pointer?

Comment: @henry. Absolutely nothing wrong. Just too easy to forget to free them. with ``vector<int> &``, you won't have these worries and also have the advantage of pointers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the vector class will probably automatically allocate a larger space than needed in case you want to store more data in it later, so it probably won't allocate new space each time you `push_back()`.
2. Yes, but you should use `delete interList;` instead of `free()`.

Comment: :- I have one question with respect to your answer number `1`. As you mentioned vector will automatically allocate a larger space, here suppose user enters more data into vector, then vector re-increases its allocated size or it doesnot allow to de same?

Comment: @Rasmi Ranjan Nayak - Yes, it will always reallocate the data to a larger space if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` copies the elements to the heap where the vector will allocate array to store the elements. The capacity of `vector` can be greater than required or greater than how many elements the vector has. Every time a push back happens the vector checks if there is enough space and if there isn't then it moves all the elements to bigger space and then push elements to the array. The vector always puts elements to contiguous memory blocks and hence if the memory block is not large enough to hold all elements together then it moves all the elements to larger block and appends new elements. In order to avoid this frequent moving the vector would usually allocated bigger memory block.

`delete interList` would destroy the vector and the integers hold by the vector. Here the vector would be on heap as well as the integers also would be on heap. Actually it is better to create the vector on stack or as a member of other object like `vector<int> interList;` The vector though on stack stores the elements of int on heap as a array. And as ints are stored as value types then once the vector goes out of scope then the memory of ints would be reclaimed.

Because the vector has value types. They are copied to heap by the vector and stored and managed as arrays and their lifetime is attached with vector's lifetime. If you have a vector of pointers then you have to worry. Like `vector<T*> list;` `list.push_back(new T());` The list stores pointers to objects of type `T`. When you destroy such vector the `T` objects would not be deleted. This is same like a class with a pointer to a `T*`. You have to loop through all the element and call delete on pointers or use vector of shared pointers. Vector of shared pointers or unique pointers is recommended.

Comment: Why "it is better to create vector on stack"? It depends on your needs actually. OP might want to create some vector inside the method and then return pointer to the caller, so it's perfectly valid use case also.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the need and unless the need create on stack. Or as a member of another class by value. So that you don't have to remember to call delete.

Answer (score 1):

std::vector allocates continuos block of memory at once for some amount of elements. So every time you insert new element it is inserted into reserved block, and the memory space remains the same, no new allocation happens.

If you insert element beyond the allocated block (capacity of the vector) then it allocates a bigger block (resize), copies all the previous elements into it and destroys the old block. So vector manages memory by itself, not each inserted element cause reallocation of the internal buffer.

Second question - yes, vector will clean up all the memory if you delete vector itself.

```
delete interList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off not directly allocating the vector if you can help it. So your code would look like this:

```
vector<int> interList;
interList.push_back(1);
interList.push_back(2);
interList.push_back(3);
interList.push_back(4);
```

Now when interList goes out of scope *all* memory is freed. In fact this is basis of all resource management of C++, somewhat prosaically called RAII (resource acquisition is initialization).

Now if you felt that you absolutely *had* to allocate your vector you should use one of the resource management smart pointers. In this case I'm using shared_ptr

```
auto interList =  std::make_shared<vector<int>>();
interList->push_back(1);
interList->push_back(2);
interList->push_back(3);
interList->push_back(4);
```

This will now also free all memory and you never need to call delete. What's more you can pass you interList around and it will reference count it for you. When the last reference is lost the vector will be freed.